# How do I automatically answer "yes" to a prompt in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How can I input "yes" as an answer to an interactive question in a PowerShell session? I know, in Bash, `Yes` is the tool to answer "yes" on the prompt. In my situation, I can't suppress the prompt.

The script I'm running stops at

> Please reply "yes" if you want to continue:

How powershell can run the script and "answer" yes when pompted?

Comment: Need more context, for instance what is cfgsave ? Is it something you wrote or are you just trying to use Powershell to run it. How would cfgsave work without Powershell, it sounds like it would display a window with a 'yes' button?

Comment: This is asking for a way to pass input to a shell prompt.

Answer (score 23):

Using ECHO worked for me. I am running RSKeyMgmt.exe in my Powershell script and it prompted Yes(Y)/ No(N). So when I do

`ECHO Y | RSKeyMgmt.exe...`

It did not prompt the question and the command was executed correctly.

So I think `ECHO 'someoption'` should work for other cases too.

Answer (score 23):

I was also having the same issue.
The solutions tried by me included:

- ECHO 'Y' |
- Command-Name -Force
- $ConfirmPreference = 'None'

However, none of them seemed to do the trick.

What finally solved the problem was:

```
Powershell-Cmdlet -Confirm:$false
```

It suppresses all confirmation prompts for the duration of the command and the command would be processed without any confirmation.

Comment: `$ConfirmPreference = 'None'` worked for me so thanks for including it in your answer

Answer (score 12):

Inspired by other answers, here is my example:

```
ECHO Y | powershell Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Answer (score 8):

You can test these old fashion ways :

```
Cmd /c "GpUpdate.exe /FORCE <C:\temp\response.txt"

ECHO 'Y' | GpUpdate.exe /FORCE

Get-Content "C:\temp\response.txt" | GpUpdate.exe /FORCE
```

Comment: I am just using powershell to run it. CFGsave is an external command run on a switch. I would like to run this command from powershell without having to respond to yes or no. Also thanks JP but i would prefer powershell workaround if it exists. :) for my learning more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when installing something from an "untrusted source":

```
ECHO Y | powershell Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate | ECHO Y
```

I was trying to programmatically install the Windows Update powershell tool set :)

Answer (score 0):

For Azure CLI commands --yes is often an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Disable-NetAdapter -name "Wi-Fi" -Confirm:$false
```

This worked for me in this scenario with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it wasn't just a yes/no option.  I had some scripts that prompted for a choice of multiple options and I wanted to include them in some automated scripts. The prompts were something like this:

```
Select Option
What option do you want to use:
[A] Option A  [B] Option B  [C] Option C  [?] Help (default is "A"):
```

I found that this worked:

```
Echo A | powershell.exe ./script.ps1
```

Echo is simply an alias for 'Write-Output'. If there were more than one prompt, I could simply separate the inputs with a space like:

```
Echo A F G
```

I don't know why I needed to include the powershell.exe instead of just passing in the echo into the script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the echo command in the front, (which will just echo all following inputs, or throw an error about the pipe) I put it at the end and that worked.

```
Install-Module -Name DisplaySettings | ECHO Y
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue trying to use:

```
net use * /delete
```

It always prompeted me for a Y/N and tried the solutions in here but none worked, so I'm reporting what worked for me:

```
net use * /delete /y
```

Maybe every command has a silent confirmation.

Comment: or maybe not. or maybe most likely not. or maybe even most certainly those that do may use different syntax. just maybe.

Answer (score -1):

-Confirm:$false - THIS ONE IS WORKING JUST FINE.

Comment: Does this depend on the command/function being ran?

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to kill a pesky startup program and found that the Stop-Process and / or the program would not accept a piped input (no Echo Y | for me!) but I changed JPs answer a little bit:  Stop-Process -name [program.name] -Force ; ran as administrator and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

The following Powershell worked for me:

```
Write-Output 'Y' | .\plink.exe <ip_address> -l <username> -pw <password>
```

This will output the 'Y' character to the next pipeline object.

Comment: `echo` is an alias for write-output