# Azure CLI skip overwrite flag

Tags: bash, azure

Created a bash script to bulk upload images to Azure, and happened so that few images were not uploaded and I don't know which ones. When I run the script if it finds that blob already exists it asked me if I want to overwrite it (Y/N). Is there a flag to say No to all?

```
for loop..
azure storage blob upload $file $storage $fileName
echo -e "$region;$cuid;$url" >> file.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yes` utility:

```
yes N | azure storage blob upload $file $storage $fileName
```

> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or ‘y’.

Comment: Hi, klashxx, do you know if there is a same usage for powershell?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071012/how-do-i-automatically-answer-yes-to-a-prompt-in-powershell