# Fill Powershell Interactive Prompt from .csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a `.jar` file from Powershell that requires the user to input four parameters through Command Prompt after executing the `.jar`. Each parameter is inputed as a new line. I would like to automatically read these parameters in from a `.csv` where each line contains one parameter.

I currently run the `.jar` by calling `java -cp some.jar`. The `.csv` and `.ps1` are in the same directory.

I know with Shell this could be done with `cat parameters.csv |`. Is there an equivalent in PS? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071012/how-do-i-automatically-answer-yes-to-a-prompt-in-powershell) is related but does not deal with reading a `.csv`.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I've never written in powershell before, so just an extensive google search

Comment: Then you may want to peruse a PowerShell tutorial first. SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with a language you haven't used before. But to give you a starting point, the usual approach to something this in PowerShell is to construct an array or hashtable from the CSV data and then [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) that on the command.