# Make npx silently install latest package version, without prompting user for input

Tags: node.js

#### Synopsis

When I use `npx create-next-app@latest`, I am prompted to install a newer package version. I cannot find a parameter on `npx` to make the command silently work inside of a script.

For example, I would expect to find a parameter such as `--silent` or `--force` or `--yes`, as is common convention with other package managers.

There has to be an easy answer to this, but I honestly can't find it.

FYI I am using PowerShell as my shell environment on Windows 10, although I would expect the `npx` command to provide a parameter, instead of having to use shell features (piping) to accomplish this.

```
PS C:\git\myapp> npx create-next-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app@latest
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

The `npx --help` command doesn't produce any guidance.

```
PS > npx --help
npm exec

Run a command from a local or remote npm package

Usage:
npm exec -- <pkg>[@<version>] [args...]
npm exec --package=<pkg>[@<version>] -- <cmd> [args...]
npm exec -c '<cmd> [args...]'
npm exec --package=foo -c '<cmd> [args...]'

Options:
[--package <pkg>[@<version>] [--package <pkg>[@<version>] ...]]
[-c|--call <call>]
[-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
[-ws|--workspaces]

alias: x

Run "npm help exec" for more info
```

#### Actual Result

npx pauses execution until user input is provided.

#### Expected Result

npx automatically installs the latest version of the package and executes it, without prompting the user.

Comment: Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071012/how-do-i-automatically-answer-yes-to-a-prompt-in-powershell) apply here?

Comment: @Phix Nope that covers a different use case.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug. According to the [online documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx), the `--yes` parameter is supported on `npm exec` (aka. `npx`). However, on version `7.19.1` of `npm`, specifying the `--yes` option is ignored by the CLI.

To reproduce the problem, run a new Node.js container using the Docker CLI, using a Bash shell:

```
docker run --rm --interactive --tty node:16.5.0 bash
```

Then, run these commands inside the container:

```
npm install --global create-next-app@10.0.9
npx create-next-app@latest --yes
```

Here's the version information from the `16.5.0` container image:

```json
{
  npm: '7.19.1',
  node: '16.5.0',
  v8: '9.1.269.38-node.20',
  uv: '1.41.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.17.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.2',
  openssl: '1.1.1k+quic',
  cldr: '39.0',
  icu: '69.1',
  tz: '2021a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with npx,
`—-yes` was not working
but `-y` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the --yes parameter for the npx command itself, instead of attempting to use the args for the package being executed by npx.

Like this...

```
npx --yes create-next-app@latest
```