# Why is PowerShell script pausing when prompted for input?

Tags: powershell, scripting, ps1

I successfully ran 3 commands in my PowerShell script shortcut but after running the last command it prompts the user for "y" or "N" and in my script I want to input "y" and press enter.

After looking at other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071012/how-do-i-automatically-answer-yes-to-a-prompt-in-powershell) I have tried to ECHO the keystroke but it only works prior to the last command
[Here you can see the 1st Echo Successfully and the 2nd is stuck because it is paused or something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67uGQ.png)

**PowerShell Script**

```
ECHO 'y'

spicetify config current_theme Sleek
spicetify config color_scheme futura
spicetify apply

ECHO 'y'
```

Comment: That last line _prompts the user for "y" or "N"_ comes from `spicetify apply` and has nothing to do with PowerShell. Overall your script is more like a cmd than PowerShell.. You even use `Echo` (which happens to be an alias for `Write-Output`)

Answer (score 2):

- To feed automated responses to external programs that request interactive input, *pipe* those responses to them, which they receive via their *stdin* stream.
- Note that, as of PowerShell 7.3.1, a *trailing newline* (CRLF on Windows, LF on Unix) is automatically and invariably appended to a string you output from PowerShell so that, on Windows, sending `'y'` in effect sends `` "y`r`n" ``, and that newline is usually interpreted as *submitting* input to an interactive prompt.

  - While this can be convenient, there are situations in which it is problematic - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375).

Therefore, for *every* one among your `spicetify` calls that may / does prompt for a `y/n` response, do the following, using your last command as the example:

```bash
'y' | spicetify apply
```

<sup>Note how string literal `'y'` by itself is enough to produce output - no need for `echo`, which in PowerShell is an alias for the rarely needed `Write-Output` cmdlet - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375) for more information.</sup>